# How to stop Google ads from slowing down my website?

Tags: html, pagespeed, google-website-optimizer

I am using the Google Chrome profiler to run a speed audit on my site.

It is complaining about a file show_ads_impl.js

I am not 100% sure where that is coming from? I took out AdSense from my page and now just have the Google AdWords retargeting being set. But I added the async tag to that script.

This is the page I am working on: [here](http://www.problemio.com/business/business-plan-book.php)

And here is the screenshot of the profiler's complaint:

[image]

Also, the profiler suggests to use

```
<link rel="preload">
```

But where do I add that?

Comment: If I'm reading that correctly that just says that `show_ads_impl.js` itself is loading an additional stylesheet so you can speed things up if you pre-load that particular stylesheet so when loading the js it's overall faster

Comment: @apokryfos I don't think that stylesheet is explicitly mentioned. I put an async tag on all my JS, but it still has this problem.

Comment: your problem might go away if you don't execute async actually.

Comment: @apokryfos why do you think that?

Comment: The problem seems to be that while that script is loading or initializing it is blocking the screen rendering. If it's async this happens when the page is considered "interactive" which is bad user experience. If it happens before the screen is interactive then it will not have the same effect (but will increase time until screen is interactive). I guess doing a preload on it can also work I guess by reducing the download time

Comment: But where do I place the actual preload code?

Comment: According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Preloading_content you put this in the `<head>` and it would be something like `<link rel="preload" href="show_ads_impl.js" as="script" />`

Comment: That actually seemed to work! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're noticing that Google ads are slowing down your website, there are a few things you can do to help speed things up. First, make sure that you're using asynchronous loading for your ads. This means that the ads will load in the background while the rest of your [website loads](https://thesmokerpro.com/). You can also try using a cache plugin to cache your ads. This way, they'll be loaded from the cache instead of from the server every time a page is loaded. Finally, you can try using a content delivery network (CDN) to deliver your ads. A CDN can help to speed up the delivery of your ads by distributing them across multiple servers.

Answer (score -1):

You would add the link rel... to the head section of the page. One trick I use is to load the page, then the scripts on the page. I'm not sure where you currently have the scripts linked in your markup, but try linking them down at the bottom, just above the Body closing tag. The whole page loads, then the ads load - same time total, but the user won't notice.

```
...
...
<script type='text/javascript' src='googlyads.com/ads.js'>
</body>
```